# In Bash, How to run expression only, not as command

Tags: bash

e.g.

```
a=0
a=$((a+1))
# But I want to 
$((a++))
# This report 1 is not a command
```

How can I run this expression only ?

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `$`:

```
a=0
((a++))
```

Comment: Or `: $((a++))` if you want to stay POSIX-compliant.